# How to sort a ListView by a column?

Tags: c#, listview

So far I'm able to sort a ListView:

```
lsvRequestParameters.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

However, doing so list from the first column. Is there a way to sort from a column other than the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the item sorter

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(columnToBeSortedBy);
```